Virtual layer combined with x layer in group (QGIS)
Is it possible to combine a virtual layer with a layer in group? For my project:

I create a group "A"
place a point layer "A"
place a virtual layer "A" with a little script of intersection of boundary

Now I need this group as a template for further point group, but the name of the point layer is another and the group name also (lets say "B"). Inside this layer it should automaticly place a virtual layer with the script and the name of the point layer in this group. Or the underlaying point layer´s name.
So I will need to create a template stack with one point layer and one virtual layer. Is this possible?
EDIT:
or is it possible, to get point layers id (number) to substract it from virtual layers id. E.g. pointlayer ID 10, virtLayer ID 11, so I know, 11-1 (underlaying) is 10.

I doubt a VL can use another layer by relative position. An alternative would be to create a small python script that creates the VL using the name of the selected layer and places the new VL right below the selected one in the table of content.

how to do this "VL can use another layer by relative position"? the script must work in QField (later) too. I can create it in QGIS and export the project to QField.
